# How to scrape multiple webpages stemming from one page using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

recently I have been attempting to scrape a large amount of pricing from a website by starting with one page that has each item's page linked to the starting page. I was hoping to run a script which allowed me to click a box for a certain item, scrape that item's pricing and description, and then go back to the starting page and continue in that loop. However, there was an obvious problem which I ran into after scraping the first item. After going back to the starting page, the containers are not defined and thus a stale element error is given which breaks the loop and prevents me from getting the rest of the items. This is the sample code I used, hoping to scrape all the items one after another.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Hank\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_440_Collection%5B%5D=any&category_440_Type%5B%5D=tag_misc&category_440_Quality%5B%5D=tag_rarity4&appid=440#p1_price_asc')

import time

time.sleep(5)

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

action = ActionChains(driver)

next_button=wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'searchResults_btn_next')))

def prices_and_effects():
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    imgs = wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.market_listing_item_img.economy_item_hoverable')))
    for img in imgs:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(img).perform()
        print([my_element.text for my_element in wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item_desc_description div.item_desc_descriptors#hover_item_descriptors div.descriptor")))])
    prices = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.market_listing_price.market_listing_price_with_fee')
    for price in prices:
        print(price.text)

def unusuals():
    unusuals = wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.market_listing_row.market_recent_listing_row.market_listing_searchresult')))
    for unusual in unusuals:
        unusual.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        next_button=wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'searchResults_btn_next')))
        next_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        back_button=wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'searchResults_btn_prev')))
        back_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        prices_and_effects()
        ref_val = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchResults_start'))).text
        while next_button.get_attribute('class') == 'pagebtn':
            next_button.click()
            wait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'searchResults_start'))).text != ref_val)
            prices_and_effects()
            ref_val = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchResults_start'))).text
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
        time.sleep(2)
        unusuals = wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.market_listing_row.market_recent_listing_row.market_listing_searchresult')))

unusuals()
```

After scraping the first item, however, which it does successfully, it goes back to the page and throws a stale element error. The error makes sense to me, but is there any way to circumvent this so I can keep the functions and use the loop?

Comment: Maybe selenium is overkill and scrapy would be just fine. You would have to define a "home page" scrapper and an "item" scrapper, then start the scrapping of the home page, which creates a list of items, which will be scrapped by the item scrapper

Comment: And scrapy can get content using JS, dynamic elements?

Comment: Indeed seems like you need JS for paging. I believe my initial comment about a Home scrapper and an Item scrapper would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is overkill for this. You can just imitate HTTP GET requests to the same APIs that your browser makes requests to when rendering the page. Just be careful that you don't make more than 100,000 daily requests to the Steam API. Also, if the requests happen too frequently, the Steam servers extrapolate and will stop responding to requests until a certain timeout has expired, even if you aren't anywhere near reaching the 100,000 daily requests limit - that's why I added some `time.sleep`s for good measure after each request using the `item_id`.

First, you make a request to the market listings page - the one that shows all the items. Then, for each item in our list of results, we extract the item's name, and we make a request to that item's overview page and extract the item's `item_id` from the HTML using a regular expression. Then, we make another request to `https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram` to get the most recent price information for that item.

Feel free to play around with the `start` and `count` query string parameters in the `param` dictionary. Right now it just prints information for the first ten items:

```
def main():

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    import time

    url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/"

    params = {
        "query": "",
        "start": "0",
        "count": "10",
        "search_descriptions": "0",
        "sort_column": "price",
        "sort_dir": "asc",
        "appid": "440",
        "category_440_Collection[]": "any",
        "category_440_Type[]": "tag_misc",
        "category_440_Quality[]": "tag_rarity4"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    time.sleep(1)

    item_id_pattern = r"Market_LoadOrderSpread\( (?P<item_id>\d+) \)"

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.json()["results_html"], "html.parser")

    for result in soup.select("a.market_listing_row_link"):
        url = result["href"]
        product_name = result.select_one("div")["data-hash-name"]
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            response.raise_for_status()
            time.sleep(1)

            item_id_match = re.search(item_id_pattern, response.text)
            assert item_id_match is not None
        except:
            print(f"Skipping {product_name}")
            continue

        url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram"

        params = {
            "country": "DE",
            "language": "english",
            "currency": "1",
            "item_nameid": item_id_match.group("item_id"),
            "two_factor": "0"
        }

        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()
        time.sleep(1)

        data = response.json()
        highest_buy_order = float(data["highest_buy_order"]) / 100.0

        print(f"The current highest buy order for \"{product_name}\" is ${highest_buy_order}")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Cadaver's Cranium" is $12.16
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Backbreaker's Skullcracker" is $13.85
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Hard Counter" is $13.04
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Spiky Viking" is $14.26
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Carouser's Capotain" is $12.72
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Cyborg Stunt Helmet" is $12.89
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Stately Steel Toe" is $12.67
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Bloke's Bucket Hat" is $12.71
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Pugilist's Protector" is $12.94
The current highest buy order for "Unusual Shooter's Sola Topi" is $13.25
>>>
```